# How to determine unknown values of a matrix to satisfy conditions about its kernel, image and preimage

Tags: linear-algebra

The following task has been set as follows:

Let $α ∈ C$, let $b = (6, −4, 6)^t$ and let $f_a: C^3 \rightarrow C^3$ be the linear map: [image]

determine all $\alpha \in C$ such that:

a) $\ker(f_a) = \{0\}$
b) $b$ has infinitely many preimages
c) $b \notin \operatorname{im}(f_α)$

---

thoughts so far:

for part a), this question could be reformulated as: find values of alpha such that the above matrix can be row reduced in such a way that all rows contain pivots and there are no 0 rows.

for part b), i think this means that the matrix would have nullity of $1$

for part c), there exists no vector such that the matrix multiplied by said vector would yield the vector $b.$

If these suppositions are correct, how could I set up the problem in a systematic way to determine appropriate alpha values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your mathematical expressions instead of pasting pictures that aren’t searchable and don’t show up in summaries or searches. You can find a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a) you can start doing row reduction without plugging in a value of $\alpha$, and then see what happens, i.e. what you need $\alpha$ to be in order to avoid getting a row of zeros.

For b), I think it is sufficient to have nonzero nullity. You can reuse your row reduction work in a), but here your goal is to get a row of zeros.

For c), you are right. Note that the only $\alpha$ that you have to check are the ones you find in part b). (Why?)

---

If you do row reduction you can get the matrix to look like

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 & \alpha \\ & 1 & \alpha-1\\ & & 9-\alpha^2\end{bmatrix},$$
so the answer to a) is "$\alpha \ne \pm 3$", and the answer to b) is $\alpha = \pm 3$.

For c), check the two cases $\alpha = \pm 3$ and see if $b$ is in the column space in each case.

Comment: sorry, thats what I meant for b. okay, thanks for the hints, i'll get crunching...

Comment: for a), i calculated alpha = 1. 
for b) i caculated alpha = 11/3, which can be used to yield row 3 = {0, 8/3, 8/3} which causes the matrix to have nullity 1 and thus infinitely many preimages i think ( i dont understand the justification as to why, but my intuition says this is the solution). Im still not sure how to solve c though.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how you were able to eliminate the alpha term from the middle column of the matrix. I apologize, my maths is very deficient. For c, i could validate that entering Av = b did not have any solutions for my matrix A. I cant comment about checking the column space yet, because my level of maths means I need to inform myself about this first before I can attempt to apply it.