# How to partially eliminate an unknown term from a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a follow up question from the question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567077/how-to-determine-unknown-values-of-a-matrix-to-satisfy-conditions-about-its-kern).

I do not understand how it is possible to manipulate a matrix in such a way that the starting matrix has an unknown term in two columns and the row reduced matrix has said unknown term in one column only.

Can anyone help me understand how it is possible to achheive the following RREF?

$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 4 & 2α \\ -1 & -1 & -1\\ 1 & α + 2 & 9\end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \rightarrow \ ... \rightarrow \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & α \\ 0 & 1 & α - 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 9 - α^2\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider the operations $\frac12 R_1$, $R_1+ R_2$,$R_3-R_1$ and then finally do the operation $R_3 - \alpha \times R_2$ to go from  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 4 & 2α \\ -1 & -1 & -1\\ 1 & α + 2 & 9\end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \rightarrow \ ... \rightarrow \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & α \\ 0 & 1 & α - 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 9 - α^2\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.